# #1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, cloud-hosting

I've to import some data from a CSV file into a table of db on my Aruba server.
I use the following query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE dailycoppergg
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
        (
            ddmmyy,
            lmedollton,
            changedolleuro,
            euroton,
            lmesterton,
            delnotiz,
            girm,
            sgm
        )
```

I tested this query on other Aruba server and it worked correctly but here, I've the following error:

```
#1148 - Il comando utilizzato non e` supportato in questa versione di MariaDB
```

How can I modify my query to import csv file data into dailycoppergg table? Can you help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The query is fine, but MySQL client (`mysql`) disables local infile by default, you need to run it as `mysql --local-infile ...`, and then the same query should work.

The error message is a legacy and it's confusing.

Comment: thank you, can you tell me how can I set this from the management panel of my hosting service?

Comment: It very much depends on your hosting service, management panel, how much you are allowed to configure, what exactly you have access to, etc. First of all, if you can run queries from your panel, run `select @@local_infile`. If it says `0`, it means it is disabled on the server side for security reasons (which is rather smart), so you can forget about it. If it says `1`, it's enabled on the server, then find out what you are allowed to configure on the client side. In the unlikely case that you have access to the client config file, you can set `loose-local-infile=1` in the `[client]` section.

Comment: If you don't have access to the host where the client runs, then the question is why you need `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to begin with, since it presumes the file to exist on the client host, and without access you can't put it there. If you have FTP access to the client host, but can't access client configuration file and there are no tools in your management panel to configure client options, ask your hosting support, if you make your case, they might enable it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using phpMyAdmin, I highly recommend you just use the Import tab instead of manually entering the import query in the SQL tab. phpMyAdmin can easily import CSV files and I don't see any advantage to entering the query manually.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench Add the line below. in the Advanced Tab, check the test connection, and close.

```
OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1
```